# access-control-allow-origin issue on Image load

Tags: javascript, cors, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

Why we do not get access-control-allow-origin issue when we have img tag 
`src=urlOfdifferentDomain` element refers to different domain

like case:1

```
<img src="urlOfdifferentDomain" />
```

but we will get same error when we do case 2

```
//creating image element
a=new Image();
// image on load function
a.onload=function(){
}
// assigning src function
a.src=urlOfdifferentDomain
```

I just want to know what is the difference between these two approaches .
I also assign csp img-src in webserver to self then also image getting loaded from different domain in case 1

Answer (score 1):

Case 1 is OK because the use of image in HTML does not expose the resource (from other domain) to JavaScript, thus no security problem is caused.

Case 2 will report error because the use of `Image` object DO bring security risks for some operation such as Canvas editing, as it exposes resource from other domain to JavaScript.

UPDATE: This error is caused by browser security check. The web server doesn't know whether the request comes from html tag or from javascript call, and will return the resource anyway -- you can check the Network debug panel in browser, and see that the resource is downloaded with status 200. After the resource is downloaded and exposed to JavaScript operation. Browser will check whether the JavaScript operation on the resource has vulnerability. If yes, Access-Control-Allow-Origin error will be reported if CORS is not enabled in server.

Comment: but it should depend on webserver instead of javascript,i mean when cross domain call goes in case 1,it wil go to webserver and webser doesnot about javascript call r from html tag and it should give cross domain.what about " I also assign csp img-src in webserver to self then also image getting loaded from different domain in case 1"

Comment: @SudhanshuAgarwal The web server doesn't know whether the request comes from html tag or from javascript call, and will return the resource anyway -- you can check the Network debug panel in browser, and see that the resource is downloaded with status 200. After the resource is downloaded, the browser will check whether the fetched resource will be exposed to JavaScript. If yes, and the JavaScript operation on the resource has vulnerability, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error will be reported if CORS is not enabled in server.

Comment: @SudhanshuAgarwal If CSP is setting to `img-src 'self';`, an error will be reported: `Refused to load the image ... because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self'".`